# Why is 'goto' seen as bad form?

Tags: python-3.5, goto

I would find it very useful in Python, and am curious as to why Python doesn't have it. Thanks!

Comment: Because there are usually more better-to-read and safer ways to achieve what you want to achieve with a `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally *goto* is explicitly used to make error handling more simple and code more readable by languages like C. Python has *try* and *except* for this, so that makes the *goto* statement unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. This gave me an 'in a nutshell' answer!